# Name of the set $B:= \overline{A}\setminus A$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ denote a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. We define the set $B:=\overline{A}\setminus A$. Does the set $B$ have a special name in the literature? All I could find was the term *frontier*. But it seems that frontier is already used as an alternative name for the boundary of $A$, i.e. the set $\partial A:=\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$.

References or name suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Stupid question, asked because it's 6am where I am, but is this not the same as the interior of $A^c$?

Comment: The literature has called various sets the _boundary_, so the conventions vary. Frontier is often used instead to distinguish it from the _boundary of a manifold_, when both concepts are treated in the same book. Personally, I've come to call what you define as the set $B$ as the _residue_ of $A$, and I call the set $A \setminus A^\circ$ the _perimeter_ of $A$. Either way the names for these things are quite usually arbitrary, the important thing is to assign intuitive labels to such concepts, and to be able to talk about them more explicitly.

Comment: @Chill2Macht That would be what's defined as the _exterior_ of $A$, which is the same as the complement of the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The notion you are probably looking for is the border of a set, defined as:

\begin{equation}
    Bd\ (A) = Cl \ (A) \cap Cl \ (X - A)
\end{equation}
where $Cl$ denotes the closure in $X$. The border has some interesting properties, for example:

\begin{align}
    Cl \ (A) = Bd \ (A) \cup Int \ (A)&& Bd \ (A) \cap Int \ (A) = \varnothing
\end{align}

where $Int$ denotes the interior of a set. Note that the border of a set is a closed set. From the above, we get that if $A$ is an open set, then $Bd \ (A) = Cl \ (A) - A$.

As for the interior of a set, it is related to the closure and complement in the following way:

\begin{equation}
    Int\ (A) = X - Cl\ (X - A)
\end{equation}

For reference, Munkres’ Topology proposes the above relations as exercises for its section on closed sets.

Comment: *Wrong*. the border/boundary *isn't* the OP's operation. Compare the results when $A = [a,b)\subset\Bbb R$ in the usual topology.

Comment: **Bump**. This is what's often called the _boundary_ of a set, and is entirely distinct from the set $\overline A \setminus A$, which is actually contained in the boundary. I've come to call it the _residue_ of a set, although I'm not sure where that name comes from. Nonetheless I find that it fits rather well.